# ¿Cómo decimos "compliant" en castellano? / How can we expres the "compliant" adjective in technical vocabulary in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

En documentación técnica es común leer frases que mencionan el adjetivo 'compliant' en el sentido de que algo cumple con tal o cual norma, regulación, etc.

Con el tiempo, también se ha convertido en un adjetivo recurrente a la hora de definir cosas de forma divertida:

> ¿Puedes escribir este documento para que sea novatos 'compliant'?

Queriendo decir que algo es útil para un público concreto.

¿Existe alguna palabra en castellano para denotar esta palabra? "Obediente", "dócil" y "sumiso" son [las sugerencias de WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=compliant), pero me suenan más a juego de dominación que para lo que representa este caso particular.

---

It is very common in technical documentation to read things like

> If a business is following the rules and regulations promulgated by the International Organization for Standardization, it is said to be **ISO compliant**. ([source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/iso-compliant-61481.html))

Still, this has emerged as a recurrent adjective for random and funny things like:

> Please, could you write this document in a **newbie's compliant** way?

That is, to indicate that it is useful for the given target.

I wonder if Spanish has any adjective like this. "Obediente", "dócil" and "sumiso" are the [suggestions by WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=compliant) but they sound more appropriate for a dominance game than to indicate connection.

Comment: Se te ha olvidado mirar un poco más abajo en WordReference: **compliant with [sth]** _adj_ (respecting rules) en conformidad con *loc adj*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu), una posible traducción podría ser "conforme", y más concretamente su locución preposicional "conforme a":

> **[conforme a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AGVKXui)**
>
> 1. loc. prepos. Con arreglo a, a tenor de, en proporción o correspondencia a, de la misma suerte o manera que.

Así, tu primer ejemplo quedaría "conforme a ISO" o "conforme a la normativa ISO". Este adjetivo tiene además la connotación de sumisión que comentas, dado que *conforme* significa "que se resigna y es paciente ante la adversidad".

Lo malo es que este adjetivo no me parece adecuado para el segundo ejemplo, para el cual yo usaría más bien algo así como "adaptado para novatos".